# Scroller startScroll with negative offset

Tags: android, scroll, offset, scroller

With a positive offset, `startScroll` would scroll to the right. So with a negative offset, I'm assuming it should scroll to the left—the documentation doesn't say anything about this.

However this does not work as expected. The right scroll doesn't work the same, and the left scroll doesn't work at all.

Here's my code.

```
@Override

public void setSelection(int position) {

    int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
    int offsetToScroll = position * childWidth;
    if(offsetToScroll > scrollx) {
        mScroller.startScroll(scrollx, 0, offsetToScroll, 0);
    } else {
        mScroller.startScroll(scrollx, 0, -offsetToScroll, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroller has nothing to do with the UI - it's just a helper class that helps to compute position based on initial position and initial velocity, simulating inertia effect - see computeScrollOffset() & getCurrX()/getCurrY()

Comment: I have used getCurrX() and I need the scroller to start the scroll.

Comment: see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/ScrollView.java) how the Scroller is used in a ScrollView, mScroller field is the Scroller which simulates inertia effect